# Changing Word comment colors permanently

Tags: microsoft-word, comments

In MS Word, I change the comment color using review > tracking > advanced options > comments.

But After closing the document and opening it again, the color becomes red again (default color). How can I avoid it?

BTW, I'm using Office 2016.

[image]

Comment: I believe this should be saved in Word’s Normal template. If you are not allowing the template to be updated, this could be the problem. With that said, Office 2019, which I just checked, does not have this issue so I guess there could be the possibly of it being a problem only in the version you are running. A potential work around is an AutoExec macro placed in your Normal template that assigns the color every time Word is opened.

Comment: @RichMichaels: problem solved. Write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, check that you are allowing your Normal template to be updated. Word should hold the setting for this there. There is a potential that it is an Office 2016 issue because, in my testing with Office 2019, the Comment coloring setting is saved.

To work around the issue in Office 2016, write an AutoExec routine that sets the Comment color. Add this to your Normal template.

If you take the macro approach add the following into the ThisDocument object of your Normal template.

```
Sub AutoExec()
    With Application.Options
        If .CommentsColor <> Word.WdColorIndex.wdByAuthor Then .CommentsColor = Word.WdColorIndex.wdByAuthor
    End With
End Sub
```

You can use any of the available indexed colors. For example, if you want Yellow the name is wdYellow.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such an AutoExec macro?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I have updated my answer with an example as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check that the Normal Template is updated.
You can add it to you Template, To your Normaal Template. That's he only way i find to do this!

Comment: This duplicates Rich Michaels advice in the other, more comprehensive, answer.